# I can not change the background of the button when pressed

Tags: android

I have a button with the background. I need that when you click on it, the background changed, and when I release it, the background is the same.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
               if (v.isEnabled()){
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_pressed);
               }else if (!v.isEnabled()){
                   btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_normal);
               }
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

when I write this code, the background changes once and always in a state of becoming "pressed"

Comment: `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { Log.i("TAG", "touched " + v.getId());...` check if your touch event is triggered

Comment: Used selector instead of onTouch(......)

Comment: Thank you so much! Shabbir Dhangot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create xml into drawable.

button_effect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_green_dark"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_green"></item>
</selector>
```

Now set this xml to button background property.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

         btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_pressed);
         break;              
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

         btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_normal);
         break;
    }
}
```